# preprocessing an environment map with PMREMGenerator

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to understand how to preprocess envMaps correctly with the `PMREMGenerator.`

My current situation:

I create a PMREM immediately after setting up my scene, and compile its equirectangular shader (that compile step is not clear to me, but that's what I've seen in examples):

```
 this.mPmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(this.mRenderer);
this.mPmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();
```

Next, I use TextureLoader to load the envmap texture, and in its callback, I use `fromEquirectangular` to preprocess the envmap into a `RenderTarget`, and extract the new texture from it and return it.

```
private preprocessEnvMap(pEnvMap: Texture) { 
     const WorldContext.mainScene.pmremGenerator;
     return aPmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(pEnvMap).texture;
}
```

Finally, I take the returned texture, assign it as my material's `envMap`, and call the material's `needsUpdate = true`.

The result is that I get a shader error:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog No compiled fragment shader when at least one graphics shader is attached.
```

Help will be much appreciated,

Thanks

EDIT:

This is an example where I use the `PMREMGenerator` with a standard material:
https://codepen.io/tfreifeld/pen/OJWgdem

You can see that both the image in the background and in the envmap are blurry.

This is the original image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFNqH.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (that compile step is not clear to me, but that's what I've seen in examples):

This is done in order to pre-compile the internal shader. Otherwise the generator has to do this when processing an environment map. So calling `compileEquirectangularShader()` just distributes some work to the application start.

> Next, I use TextureLoader to load the envmap texture, and in its callback, I use fromEquirectangular to preprocess the envmap into a RenderTarget, and extract the new texture from it and return it.

Keep in mind that you *should* use `PMREMGenerator` with HDR textures for best quality (although it is not mandatory). So you probably want a setup where you use `RGBELoader`, `RGBMLoader` or `EXRLoader` instead of `TextureLoader` as well as respective HDR textures.

> Finally, I take the returned texture, assign it as my material's envMap, and call the material's needsUpdate = true.

It should not be necessary to set `needsUpdate` to `true`.

If the error still pops up, I suggest you demonstrate the issue with a live example (so it's possible to debug the issue).

Comment: So assuming that I don't have/need HDR images for my textures, I shouldn't use `PMREMGenerator`? The regular process should be suffice? Or using the generator is a must nowadays in order to get envmaps to work right on PBR materials?

Comment: You can use the generator with LDR textures but it does not look as good as when using a HDR workflow. However, the general usage of `PMREMGenerator` is required when using a PBR material like `MeshStandardMaterial`.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much. I'll work on providing a live example. My current problem happens within a complex project. I hope I'll be able to replicate the problem in a compact example.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry, by mistake I've added my edit to your answer instead of my question. I didn't find a cancel option anywhere...

I've not added it to my question.

Comment: Yes, the background is blurry when using the output of `PMREMGenerator`. This is the expected behavior. I also don't see the mentioned shader error in the browser console.

Comment: How can I get rid of the blurriness then? (At least on the envmap. I'm less concerned about the background).
Regarding the shader error, you're right. I didn't manage to replicate it in my example. But I realized that I was working with Phong Materials and that they aren't PBR and hence needn't be passed through `PMREMGenerator` anyway. But ,my goal is to understand how to use PBR materials so their envmaps wont be blurry.

Comment: Related discussion: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/environment-map-quality-problem/24921.  The reflection in your codepen is the best possible output with `MeshStandardMaterial` regarding the sharpness of the reflection since you have set `metalness` to `1` and `roughness` to `0`. This setup imitates a perfect mirror.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230790/discussion-between-tfreifeld-and-mugen87).